# Initial Value problem with y'(x)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a math problem: $y'(x)=y^2(x)\sin(x);$   $y(0)=2$

Is this the same as: $\dfrac{dy}{y^2}=\sin(x)dx$?

or is it the same as: $\dfrac{dy}{dx}\cdot x=y^2x\sin(x)$?

Answer?:

$$\int{\frac{1}{y^2}dy}=\int{\sin(x)dx}$$
$$\frac{-1}{y}=-\cos(x)+C$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\cos(x)+C}$$
$$2=\frac{1}{\cos(0)+C}$$
$$C=\frac{-1}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: Colonel, you accidentally typed an extra $\$$ at the end of your TeX. Is $y(0)=0$?

Comment: @JessyCat, it's fixed!

Comment: Another possible ambiguity is whether $y^2(x)$ means $(y(x))^2$ or $y(y(x))$.  Given the trigonometric function, almost certainly the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $y'(x)$ and $y^2(x)$ to mean that $y'$ and $y^2$ are functions of $x$, in which case the first alternative you list is correct.

So you want to solve $$\int \frac{1}{y^2}\,dy =\int \sin(x)\, dx$$

Note also that $y(0)=2$ means $y$, evaluated at $x=0$, is equal to $2$, which is consistent with tht notational interpretation I give above.

Edit: Your evaluation of the constant $C$ is correct.

Comment: Could you check at the updated question. Is this how to do it? Or would I do $y = \frac{1}{cos(x)}+C$?

Comment: You did just fine.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach would be your first alternative, solving using $$\int \frac{1}{y^2}\,dy =\int \sin(x)\, dx$$ and remembering these are indefinite integrals.

Comment: Could you check at the updated question. Is this how to do it? Or would I do $y = \frac{1}{cos(x)}+C$?

Comment: I'm talking about the $+C$, should it go in the fraction?

Comment: Your edit to your question is exactly what I would do.  The suggestion in your comment would be wrong as the $C$ should either be added to the $-\cos(x)$ or to the $-\frac{1}{y}$; both lead to the same solution.